# Lists globaly accesible on all the aplication with DI for getting data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

The problem I want to solve is to be able to define List that data comes from a injected datasource but the list must be accessible all over the app.

Now I have this class:

```
public class InmutableLists
{       
    public static List<Empresa> ListaEmpresas = new EmpresaRepositorioBD().ObtenerEmpresas().ToList();
    public static List<Sala> ListaSalas = new SalaRepositorioBD().ObtenerSalas().ToList();
    public static List<Maquina> ListaMaquinas = new MaquinasRepositorioBD().ObtenerMaquinas().ToList();
    public static List<Tecnica> ListaTecnicas = new TecnicasRepositorioBD().ObtenerTecnicas().ToList();
}
```

The problem is that the datasource is explicit XX_RepositorioBD, I have several datasources for these lists (files, xml, etc) I would like to be able to use Ninject to inject the proper data source. So instead of EmpresaRepositorioBD using IEmmpresaRepositorio. Like:

```
public static List<Empresa> ListaEmpresas = new IEmpresaRepositorio.ObtenerEmpresas().ToList();
```

But I can't figure it out. I tried with [inject] on the list and a singleton but it didn't work. At the end I need to feed some UI componete like:

```
comboBoxModel.Datos = InmutableLists.ListaMaquinas;
```

Any advice? Now it is working but coupled to the BD source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject supports "Multi Injection", see https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection
Now the problem is, that when you want to inject enumerable types, like array (`Foo[]`), Enumerable (`IEnumerable<Foo>`), collection (`ICollection<Foo>`) or list (`IList<Foo>`) (and maybe even some more) binding them does not work, but instead ninject will look for all bindings of `Foo` and instanciate each binding and then return these as the requested enumerable.

Long story short, the following does not work:

```
this.Kernel.Bind<IList<Foo>>().ToConstant(new List<Foo> { foo1, foo2 });
```

To work around this, you can create your own collection type:

```
public class EmpresaList : List<Empresa> { }
```

and bind it:
    this.Kernel.Bind().ToMethod(ctx => InmutableLists.ListaEmpresas);

(of course you can also create a singleton binding, constant binding,.. or what ever you like/need)

EDIT: for your example you could use:

```
this.kernel
    .Bind<EmpresaList>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => new EmpresaList(
                     ctx.Kernel.Get<IEmpresaRepositorio>()
                               .ObtenerEmpresas()))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: So, the thing is removing the static operator on the Lists and use the ToConstant operator? Could I acess the list in the same way? InmutableList.Lista?

Comment: No, the thing is that you need to implement a specific list type (`EmpresaList`) because ninject otherwise recognizes it as "multi binding". I've updated the answer with an example.